# PHP SSL connection to MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I’ve difficulties with connection to MongoDB on DigitalOcean using crt file. My code is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$conn = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://[app]-ad319710.mongo.ondigitalocean.com', array(
    'username' => 'doadmin',
    'password' => '[password]',
    'db'       => 'aircraft',
    'authSource' => 'admin',
    'replicaSet' => '[app]',
    'ssl' => 'true',
    'sslCAFile' => '/usr/share/ca-certificates/app/ca-certificate.crt'
));

$db = $conn->aircraft;
$collection = $db->data;
?>
```

I am getting an error: *‘Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found’*. I installed driver in this way:

- sudo pecl install mongodb
- sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini → extension=mongodb.so
- cd /var/www/html
- sudo composer require mongodb/mongodb

I can connect using MongoDB client, but only with certificate. Connection string as follows:
mongodb+srv://doadmin:[password]@[app]-ad319710.mongo.ondigitalocean.com/aircraft?authSource=admin&replicaSet=[app]&tls=true&tlsCAFile=ca-certficate.crt

[phpinfo() mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBZyo.png)

MongoDB client: 4.4.6
MongoDB server: 4.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Issue from mongodb php driver: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/484 , it is not related to crt.

Can be fixed by this cmd

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

Comment: I don't use SELinux